# Using two onclick functions for one button

Tags: android

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (!q1.isChecked() && q2.isChecked())
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.negative).show();         
    } 
}


public void onClick(View v)
{
    if (q1.isChecked() && !q2.isChecked())
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show();         
} 
}
```

How do I make this code work? I know that the two if conditions can be in a single `OnClick` function, but how do I make two if conditions from separate functions work on one button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `onClick` method twice. Use a `if else`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (!q1.isChecked() && q2.isChecked()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.negative).show();         
    } 
    else if(q1.isChecked() && !q2.isChecked()) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show();         
        } 
}
```

Pls have a look @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Your comments makes no sense to me.

Comment: yes i know that i dont need 2 onClick but..it is what our professor required to us and thats what makes me crazy.. @Raghunandan

Comment: @user3322959 if you have 2 different buttons then its a different case. Either you understood your professor wrong or your professor might me wrong in this case. `OnClickListener` is a interface. Your class implements the interface or you use annonymous inner class. So i don't know what you mean by 2 on click methods for same button

Comment: my professor actually did it and he showed us that it is possible and he want us to make a that code.. @Raghunandan

Comment: @user3322959 put your professors code here. we can't imagine what you are telling or what your professor is doing

Comment: LOL..unfortunately he dont give us his code..coz it is his challenge to us..anyway..thank you for the time..@Raghunandan

Comment: @user3322959 you can have long click listener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html. To me what you say make no sense

Comment: can you e-mail me at rheymarc_depo2@yahoo.com? coz stackoverflow is saying "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" @Raghunandan

Answer (score 1):

put two part in one listener and handle with `if else`

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (!q1.isChecked() && q2.isChecked()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.negative).show();         
            } 
   else if (q1.isChecked() && !q2.isChecked()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show();         
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (!q1.isChecked() && q2.isChecked()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.negative).show();         
            } 
if (q1.isChecked() && !q2.isChecked()) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show();         
            } 
}
```